# How to float DIVs from right to left inside a container? (can't use position absolute + right:0)

Tags: css

I have the following code:

html:

```
<div class=container1>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
       test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
       test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=container2>
    hover
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative !important;
  width: 500px
}

.container2 {
  background: blue;
  border: solid;
  float: left !important;
  height: 200px;
  /*position: relative; can't use, as it would limit icons inside this container*/
  width: 110px;
  }
.container2:hover .box {
  display: block;
}

.box {
    border: solid;
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    /*right:0;*/
}
.icon{
  background: white;
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tombrito/81oq7mde/8/

Is there a way to make the `.icon` itens expand to the left, instead of to the right?

I can't use `position:absolute` + `right:0`, as they would get out of `.container2`. And I can't make `container2` `position:relative`, as it would limit the icons inside it.

Comment: would `direction` be an answer  ? http://jsfiddle.net/81oq7mde/9/

Comment: How is this supposed to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, `direction` seems to be the thing to reverse layout behavior:

```css
.container1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative !important;
  width: 500px
}

.container2 {
  background: blue;
  border: solid;
  float: left !important;
  height: 200px;
  direction:rtl;
  width: 110px;
  }
.container2:hover .box {
  display: block;
}

.box {
    border: solid;
    display: none;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    /*right:0;*/
}
.icon{
  background: white;
  border: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class=container1>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
       test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=container2>
    <div class="box">
       test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=container2>
    hover
    <div class="box">
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
      <div class="icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the containers are all separate you can't achieve what you are looking for with a float, however here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/81oq7mde/10/) of what I believe you are looking for.
Maybe not the greatest solution but it works.

```
.container2:hover .box {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -195px;
}

.box {
    border: solid;
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    /*right:0;*/
}
.icon{
  background: white;
  border: solid;
  float: right;
  width: 30px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: That margin-left would be variable, but it's a starting idea... thanks!

Comment: I think GCyrillus had a better answer with direction

Answer (score 0):

make changes to your `.box`

here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81oq7mde/12/). You need to add a width to your `.box` and make it `float:right`

```
.box {
    border: solid;
    display: none;
    min-width:150px;
    max-width: 300px;
    float:right;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    top: 50px;
    /*right:0;*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the icons should expand to the left end of `.container1`. Like they are doing to the right on the original code.

Comment: It cannot work without a fixed `width` or atleast a `min-width`